# Should I use OData or develop my own WCF service?

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, odata

I have a project to expose Entity Framework data via a web service. I am wondering should I use OData or write my own WCF services? It seems that OData is dead. Am I right?

Comment: *Tales of my death have been greatly exaggerated* ... **why** do you think OData is dead??

Comment: I see a lot of book and web logs and ... about WCF but nothing about OData. I was wondering why nobody using it, Is it dead?

Comment: It's certainly **NOT DEAD!** Read the WCF Data Services team blog - lost of activity - see the http://www.odata.org web site - a new v3 protocol spec is just being worked on - dead!?!?!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The WCF Data Services team has just recently published a new [WCF Data Services v5.1.0 (RC)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2012/04/20/wcf-data-services-5-1-0-rc-prerelease.aspx) release....

I don't see any signs of a demise here, really.... read their team blog! They've even [announced to be releasing **more frequently** in the future](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2012/05/07/wcf-data-services-now-with-more-releases.aspx)!

Doesn't sound anything like dead to me...

Basically, OData / WCF Data Services is the fastest way to publish an Entity Framework data model to the web. If it's good enough for you, if it covers all your needs - then by all means - **USE IT!**

Comment: For people reading this and trying to find this version of WCF Data Services, it's worth pointing out that `v5.1.0 RC` got reversioned as `v5.0.1 RC` http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2012/05/07/wcf-data-services-now-with-more-releases.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Just to update this thread...

Definitely this is not dead. Check [this link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api). [OData](http://www.odata.org/introduction/) is growing up and probably it’ll be the default way to distribute APIs(REST). The new Web API (ref. Asp.Net MVC 4) gave a very important focus on it.

Comment: And do not forget to check this link also if you think it's dead... https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/odata